# Wrap button base on the link text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add buttons but I am not able to get the results I am looking for.

The following image is what I am trying to do but can not replicate:

[image]

and the results I get is the following:

[image]

Updated: my question by adding more of the css code that is being used.

Thank you all for your help.

```css
  

 .img-banner{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 display:inline;
}

body{
 position:relative;
 background-color:white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul{
 list-style:none;
}

a{ 
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Sherwood !important;
}

.navbar-buttons{
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-align:right;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 <!---background-image: url(./img/Banner.jpg);--->
 width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 940px;
 height:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }

 #banner-wrapper{
 display:block;
 padding:0;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 background:#FFF;
 background-image: url(./img/Banner.jpg);
 height:14.6%;
 padding-bottom:44px;
}

img.no-border{border: 0;}

.img-banner{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 display:block;
}

#sidebarleft{
 width: 30%;
 padding-top: 58px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 display:inline;
 float:left;
}

#sidebarleft ul.menu{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:10px 0 10px 15px;
}

.leftbuttons{
 background-image: url(./img/Button_1.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding:20px 20px;
}

.leftbuttons a{
 color:grey;
 vertical-align:center;
}

.aligntext{
 vertical-align:center;
 text-align:left;
}

#sidebarright{
 float:right;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 0; marign:0;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

img.buttonUlti{
 float:right;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:15px;
 border-radius:18px;
}

.shiftRes{
 margin-left:27px;
 padding-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
 <!-- banner-wrap starts here -->
 <div id="banner-wrapper">          
    <!-- Menu Tabs -->
  
   <ul>
    <li class="navbar-buttons"><a href="index.cfm"><span>Home</span></a>&nbsp;<span style="color:white !important">|</span>&nbsp;<a href="Resources.cfm"><span>Support</span></a></li>
    
   </ul>
 </div>

    <div id="sidebarleft">
      <h2>Departments</h2>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="leftbuttons"><a class="aligntext" href="Blah.cfm">BLAH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leftbuttons"><a href="Blah.cfm?">BLAH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leftbuttons"><a href="Blah.cfm">BLAH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leftbuttons"><a href="Blah.cfm">Room</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: CSS, position relative?

Comment: Can you post sample HTML and CSS that you currently have to produce your current output?

Comment: Hello all, updated my question. Thank You

Comment: I embedded your code in a stack snippet and it looks like you left out some important CSS

Comment: @j08691 Updated the question once again

Answer (score 0):

Any easy way to do this is use and unordered list.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
   <ul>
     <li>Claims</li>
     <li>Credentialing</li>
     <li>Customer Service</li>
     <li>Data Management</li>
     <li>Decision Support</li>
     <li>DNA Comittee</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 CSS

 ul { list-style: none; }
 li { border: 1px solid black; width: 150px; padding: 5px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8dn3q303/